# spring JPA(hibernate) + MongoDB hybrid entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, mongodb, jpa, entity

I have a spring project (JPA + hibernate) with MySQL db.

Today a new requirement has been brought to the office- 
We need to create a new entity, this entity contains email exchanges between us and the customers.

Our requirement of this entity is:

1. manipulate \ filter metadata of email exchanges.
2. save all the email bodies in the DB

Since the last requirement might lead to a DB growth we thought about creating this new emailExchange entity as a hybrid of 2 databases : the `MySQL`  for metadata and `mongodb` for the e-mail bodies.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this practice bad \ good? are there any alternatives?
2. what is the best way to implement this hybrid entitiy?

Comment: What do you mean by the Hybrid Entity? Is the metadata and the body designed to be in 2 Java classes? Or are you looking at one Java Class to be stored in MySQL and MongoDB. If its the second case then it is not a great thing to do as you are replicating the same data in 2 different databases.

Comment: the entity is comprised of 2 subentities (each on a different DB).  the first sub entity fields:  timecreated, user, isHandled, status.    the other entity fields:     List<Email> emails_correspondance